# Spring And Hibernate MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Hey guys i have stuck in the hibernate Relation with spring MVC , I have class like Student and this class is having the OneToOne relation with the Parent class ,My Error is When i tried to delete Student Object the parent Object Doesn't allow to delete the Student Object 
It is giving an error like

```
Hibernate: delete from Student where id=?
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`digischool`.`parent`, CONSTRAINT `FK_l65r4icaxmteeq1tg96t6n3ol` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`))
"
```

i have Student Model Class like

```
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Parent parent;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @OneToOne(mappedBy="student",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

Parent model class like

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String relation;
    private Student student;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="student_id")
    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public String getRelation() {
        return relation;
    }
    public void setRelation(String relation) {
        this.relation = relation;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

In order to delete Student Object i have written DAO like

```
public boolean deleteStudent(long studentId) {
        if(studentId > 0){
            Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM Student S WHERE S.id = :studentId");
            query.setParameter("studentId", studentId);
            int rowChanged = query.executeUpdate();
            if(rowChanged > 0){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My db is looks like [image: Student Db]

[image: Parent Db]

Please help me out i am new bee to this Spring World

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are forgeting to remove the relationship from the parent entity prior to deleting the student.

the way to do this:

```
public boolean deleteStudent(long studentId) {
    if(studentId > 0){
// get parent object
parent.setStudent(null); // THIS REMOVES THE RELATIONSHIP FROM PARENT CLASS SINCE ITS STORED THERE
// save parent object with emptied student field


        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM Student S WHERE S.id = :studentId");
        query.setParameter("studentId", studentId);
        int rowChanged = query.executeUpdate();
        if(rowChanged > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

FYI
use the hibernates own functions when you can.
check out this link for some ways to delete a object http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-basics-3-ways-to-delete-an-entity-from-the-datastore

Comment: Hey @Aeseir why should we manually set The parent Object to null ,I mentioned cascade type on Student Model Class know that has to take care of deleting child object Right??

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute `orphanRemoval = true` with annotation `@OneToOne` with your `Parent` entity

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

....
```

hope it help.